# Cmd returning firefox version fails when run as administrator on one particular PC

Tags: batch-file, firefox, cmd

I am trying to determine the currently installed version of firefox on a PC as part of a batch script. It works on one PC, but not another.

I have narrowed down the root cause as follows.

When I run `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -v | more` in either a batch file or in cmd, it returns `Mozilla Firefox 81.0` and a blank line. Unless I'm running the batch file or cmd session as an administrator on one particular PC, in which case it returns nothing.

To be clear:

PC 1, running cmd or batch file as standard user, returns `Mozilla Firefox 81.0`

PC 1, running cmd or batch file as administrator, returns `Mozilla Firefox 81.0`

PC 2, running cmd or batch file as standard user, returns `Mozilla Firefox 81.0`

PC 2, running cmd or batch file as administrator, returns blank line

...

PC 1 is a physical Windows 10 Enterprise machine, while PC 2 is a virtual Windows 10 Pro machine

And the kicker is, *this worked on PC 2 yesterday*

What could have changed to cause such odd behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try for this batch file : tested only on my machine : Windows 10 (32 bits)

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Get FireFox Version
@for /f "delims=" %%a in (
'Powershell -C "(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox' | Select 'CurrentVersion').CurrentVersion"'
) do (
    Set "Version=%%a"
)
echo FireFox Version = %Version%
pause
```

Comment: That works on both PC's (as admin or standard user). Would it also work on a 32 bit OS? I don't have one handy to test. Doesn't help me with understanding why I have the issue to begin with, but it gives me an option to circumvent it - thanks!

Comment: @ASForrest I tested only on my machine : Windows 10 (32 bits)